# Regex - Select number between two characters

Tags: regex, preg-match

I can't figure out how to find a digit in a string like the following: Picture15.jpg. Does anyone have a RegEx of how to extract this digit in PHP?

Comment: Have you gone through a basic tutorial for regular expressions? There's one at http://regular-expressions.info.

Comment: What about `\\d+`?? `\d` is used to match digits. There are several other meaningful escape sequences which you should really go through first.

Comment: The regex itself would be /\d+/ but I don't have the PHP function syntax in mind.

Comment: I have done [code]\d[/code] but PHP only selects the first digit and then returns it. I don't know how to get all of the digits regardless of length...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
preg_match("/(\d+)/", "Picture15.jpg", $m);
echo $m[1];
```